# Creating N links using a For Loop in Xacro

Tags: gazebo-2.2, xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I wonder if it is possible to construct a for loop to build N wheels sub-assemblies for a mobile robot in a xacro.urdf file.

I have already created an URDF using Xacro for the mobile robot and the wheel sub-assembly but I need to generate N wheels on each side of the mobile robot.

Any ideas, turnarounds or out-of-the-box solutions?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6883/creating-n-links-using-a-for-loop-in-xacro/) by [Zamzami](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/941/zamzami/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

An alternative to xacro with urdf is to use SDF with embedded ruby (see the [rigid_cart model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/default/cart_rigid_suspension/model.rsdf) for an example).

Use the following command to generate the sdf file from the rsdf template:

`erb model.rsdf > model.sdf`

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zamzami](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/941/zamzami/) on 2014-09-03**:
Thank you scpeters, i'm not familiar with ruby but it seems to be an efficient turnaround solution and merits the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you have an if statement and you can call a macro within itself, you can build recursion with a counter which breaks the recursion as it reaches zero.

```
<xacro:macro name="loop" params="links_qty">
    <!-- call some macros or do other things -->
    <xacro:if value="${links_qty}">
        <xacro:loop links_qty="${links_qty-1}" />
    </xacro:if>
</xacro:macro>

<xacro:loop links_qty="15" />
```

I just tested if this works and it does.

---

Originally posted by [benelot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3038/benelot/) with karma: 11 on 2017-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1